# open with menu does not open the application ( vs code ) after renaming account name in windows 11

Tags: windows-11, user-accounts, context-menu

OS windows 11:
Recently I have changed my account profile name from **Users** to **Keshav** and also rename the account folder name under *C:/Users*

done all the changes like change in registry --> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList

updated Path variable locations also by changing **C:/Users/users** to %USERPROFILE%

everything works fine and when check in command `whoami /user`  it gives correct result.

now issues is in open with menu, As it display VS code in menu but it does not open on click on it

[image: open with menu where vs code displayed]

I am sure there something we need to change in registry  for this open with menu entry, someone help on this.

please note, typing code from command opens vs code

### update

I chose vs code using second option and select vs code but now there are 2 vs code option in open with menu, how can I remove which is not getting open

[image: 2 vs code instance in open with menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the Microsoft Store version of Visual Studio Code :

- Open the Microsoft Store from the Start menu
- Search for "Visual Studio Code"
- Click the "Visual Studio Code" entry to show the app
- Click the "Uninstall" button.

You may still need to set the desktop version as the handler for some
file types.

In case of problems, you might need to repair the installation as
described in the article
[Repair Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022):

- Find the Visual Studio Installer on your computer in either:

  - In the Start menu search for "installer", and select
    "Visual Studio Installer"
  - Also found in
    `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\setup.exe`
- Execute the installer, if asked to update it before continuing,
  follow the prompts
- Select the installation to repair
- Select "Repair" from the "More" menu

The linked article has this note :

> Repairing Visual Studio will reset its environment. Local customizations, like per-user extensions installed without elevation, user settings, and profiles will be removed. Your synchronized settings such as themes, colors, and key bindings will be restored.

Answer (score 1):

Windows ?

What that reminds me of is what we called ghost records in database queries.

What could be happening is somewhere in your registry a numeric id is being used to represent your user, like a GUID, which could explain the multiple entries.

However other logic is being used to launch the program and its including something related to your user name which vs code may not be able to make sense of, like a default home directory.

This is an educated guess, but it is likely to do with the registry itself not being entirely updated after the change of username or extra records not being purged.

I'm guessing you chose the option in the microsoft store so that explains the added entry.

Strange it wouldn't work.

Basically this is a general guess, and it may not be something you can fix directly, however maybe you, logging into another user account and seeing if vs code works there through the shell launcher.

Second if that works, try backing up all your settings json files in vs code and giving them a quick once over to make sure they're not accessing plugins in your appdata folder or wherever your profile for vs code is being stored and then reinstalling vs code.

Comment: Vs code works fine but the open with menu vs code icon is not opening at all. btw I uninstalled and installed back and its works fine now.

Comment: so its a registry problem related to the shell itself it would seem. always remember that default in windows.

Comment: windows keeps track of a lot of extra crap it doesn't really need to to function in the registry and registry corruption used to be a problem, now it sometimes leaves a lot of extra things behind when you do things like you suggested. you may have been better off creating a new user account and migrating all your stuff over.  well the data anyway.  browser hijacks can sometimes be limited to your user profile, so may not want to copy app data over.